# Move origin to center of element?

Tags: html, css, transform

Background: In my project I scatter out small square divs (.node) on to a ”map”.

```
.node{
    position: absolute;
    width: A;
    height: A;
    left: X %;
    top: Y %;
    margin-left: -(A/2);
    margin-top: -(A/2);
}
```

As you can see i have to use margin to move the ”node” so it get centered over my coordinate.

Question: 
Is there a way in css to move origin to the center of the element so i don’t have to use margin?
I believe that ”transform-origin” only works for rotation.

Comment: Have you considered `width:0; height:0; overflow:visible`?

Comment: I will look into that Ulrich, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Why not use margins, that's what they're meant for?

Comment: bro have u tried giving transform: rotate(0deg); and then giving transform-origin guess it would help ....

Comment: @Magnus you should accept an answer if it was useful for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a negative `translateX/Y`

```
.node{
    position: absolute;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); 
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);  
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);  
}
```

since the `transform-origin` is by default `(0, 0)`, this translation will move the element by `-50%` of its size (along `x` and `y` axis).

Example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hkglh